# Do I have to register a domain name to map an IP address?

Tags: jenkins, dns

I have an Jenkins server named "jenkins" in a remote machine, and I currently use its actual IP address to access it. And I have a domain name to use for my Web server on another machine: www.mysite.com.

Is it possible to configure DNS names to use "jenkins.mysite.com" to access my Jenkins server machine without registering another independent domain name?

Further, I might have another machine to host my wiki, so I would like to access it as "wiki.mysite.com".

Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can configure DNS like that. The specifics depend on which DNS server you use. If it's a web hosting you can typically use a control panel they provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is not only possible, but extremely common. It is a perfectly ordinary use of DNS. The entity controlling `mysite.com` can add whatever names they want under it (barring some technical limitations).

The details of what you personally need to do to add those other names will, of course, depend entirely on your environment. It can be anything from editing a zone file or using a web administration interface to talking to a sysadmin.